# What should new users do when they see a bad, but not terrible question?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I see a question which lacks context, a clear question or proper grammar.

However, I cannot comment on the question because my reputation is not high enough, 'flagging' seems to be overkill, and answering the question with something like "could you provide more context" will pollute the page even further.

What would be the best course of action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can fix the question's problems, just suggest an edit! Fix everything you can.

If you *can't* fix the problem because of lacking information, then just move on. Another user will come along and ask for it.

Comment: And flagging might not be overkill in some situations.